# Auxiliary loss function for softmax confidence

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, softmax

I have a softmax as part of a neural net model. There are no labels for these softmax outputs, but I want to enforce an auxiliary loss function on the confidence of the softmax output, essentially making the model "commit" to one feature; this loss would be lower the closer one probability is to 1 and the rest to 0. What would be a good function to use for this?

Comment: You could use sparsemax instead of softmax. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02068.

Comment: Without labels, it will be a challenge to decide which probability should be largest. Without further specification, it seems like a model would just pick one target to set to 1 for all inputs, and achieve a low loss as a result, but what use would this model have?

Comment: penalizing entropy is a common approach.

Comment: Currently I'm using `exp(mean(x) - max(x))` on the unnormalized log-probabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regularization loss you came up with seems decent:

\begin{align*}
\text{L}_r(x) = \text{exp}(\text{mean}(x) - \text{max}(x))
\end{align*}

Here is a plot of the loss it gives for binomial distributions between [0,1] and [1,0]:

[image]

The steep peak might hamper early training. Like Sycorax pointed out, your model will minimize the regularization loss first before the classification loss. Worst case, it gets stuck in a local minima. You can combat this by gradually increasing the weight of your regularization loss.

---

Alternatively, you can use the entropy of the softmax distribution like shimao suggests:

\begin{align*}
\text{L}_r(x) = -\sum (x \cdot \text{ln}(x))
\end{align*}

The plot for entropy loss:

[image]

The gradient is smaller in early training, when the predictions have the highest entropy. This means the model won't prioritize the regularization loss as much and has a chance to train the classifier. It's still a good idea to adjust the weight based on some testing.